# Integrating Swing in a simple text adventure game

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am fairly new to some intermediate concepts in Java. Recently I made a text adventure game called DazzleQuest that runs entirely in the developer console/terminal. It involves my friends as characters so I wanted to show it to them and gain experience with Java by transferring the functionality of the command line and output from the console to a simple Swing interface comprised of a `JTextArea` to show the game's output and a `JTextField`, with `ActionListener`, to handle commands from the user.

My main `DazzleQuest` class contains methods called `run()` and `handleCommand()`, which I figure I need to integrate with my `Frame` class and its subclass `TextFieldHandler` [which extends `ActionListener`]. **I am wondering, in general, what is the best way to integrate these methods and classes.** My current attempts have been confusing and though I have a basic grasp on how to make different classes and methods communicate, it is tentative.

Apologies for the wordiness and lack of specificity. I would share my code but am unsure of how much and exactly what to give. If you think you can answer my question but need an example of what I have, please say so. Even pseudocode as an answer would be appreciated. Thank you! Understanding this could be very helpful for my education as a programmer.

EDIT: Here are simplified examples of my code from the version of the game that runs entirely in the developer console. This is my main class `DazzleQuest`:

```
public class DazzleQuest {

public void run() {
    listCommands();
    for (;;) {
        StdOut.println(new StringBuilder("You are in ").append(currentRoom.getName()).append(".").toString());
        StdOut.println(new StringBuilder("You can go to: ").append(currentRoom.listExits()).toString());
        StdOut.print("> ");
        handleCommand(StdIn.readLine());
        StdOut.println();
    }

public void handleCommand(String line) {
        String[] words = line.split(" ");
        if (words[0].equals("look"))
            look();
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my current `JFrame` setup, in the `Frame` class:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public static JTextField field;
    public JTextArea area;

    public Frame() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        area = new JTextArea(20, 40);
        area.setEditable(false);

        field = new JTextField(20);
        add(area);
        add(field);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

         TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler();

            field.addActionListener(handler);
        }

        public class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener{

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                String line = field.getText();
                area.append(line + "\n");
                field.setText("");
            }
        }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Frame test = new Frame();
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

I know how to print output to the `JTextArea` instead of to the console. My issue is how exactly to get `handleCommand()` to work with `actionPerformed()` in the `Frame` class, or whether I should set up an action listener in the main class or something like that. Any examples of implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again for anything you can tell me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, regarding including code, you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to help us help you.

Now, given that you haven't provided any code (yet!) giving suggestions on how you should structure your program is a bit tricky. But I'll make an attempt anyways and might edit the answer when you've provided a MWE.

In your case, `JTextArea` is really just a fancy `System.out.print` as you will only use it to display the text that your adventure game outputs (if I'm understanding you correctly). So basically, you can write a method that accepts a string, and that method will append that string to your `JTextArea`. Then just replace your current output-lines with this method.

Then you have your `JTextField` which you want to replace your (I'm guessing) `Scanner(System.in)` with. I assume you know how to set up an action listener that responds to `Enter` or a `submit`-button.
How to set these up is not all that strange, and lots of guides talk about how to do it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html gives a good example.

Now, in general regarding the structure of your program.
You do **not** want to be dependent on *how* the user enters the text or how you display it. What I mean with this is that you do not want input- or display-logic to meddle with your game (*business*) logic. Your game logic should just receive input, from where ever, and output it to where ever. How and what the calling functions then decide to do with the information is not for the game logic to care about.

So, applied to the method names you posted. I assume `run()` is where you kick things off. As you have output that you always  want to display, you might want to pass in an `interface` here that has the method `print(string)` (or the like) which should be a method that prints the text to whatever text-element is used to display the text, be it `System.out` or `JTextArea`. The `run()` method never needs to know.
`handleCommand()` should also just accept a value (I assume a String) and handle it like it should, no matter who or what called it.

I'm having trouble giving you more advice with no code. But my general recommendation is: Don't mix presentation logic with business logic. And give each method as little info as possible, because giving them more than they actually need usually leads to a less flexible flow and structure.

---

EDIT now that some code has been added.

> I know how to print output to the JTextArea instead of to the console. My issue is how exactly to get handleCommand() to work with actionPerformed() in the Frame class

Go with the `actionPerformed()` approach. I recommend this because you won't have to bother with as much if you decide to `Thread` your application sometime in the future (multiplayer?). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html gives some good info about how to write your listener. But I'll give you some suggestion code as well.

```
...
area.setEditable(false);

field = new JTextField(20);
field.addActionListener(new SendText());    
....

class SendText implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getSource() == field){
            String str = field.getText();
            if(!str.equals("")){
                commandHandler.handle(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then rewrite your `run()` method

```
public void run(){
   ui.print(commandHandler.listCommands());

   while(true){
       if(commandHandler.continue()){
           ui.print(commandHandler.events());
       }
   }
}
```

So now you have a very small `run()` method that has no real tie-in to either the logic or the display. `ui.print(str)` is a method that your `UI` class (`Frame` in your case) that just appends what ever string is sent to it to it's drawing area, be it `System.out` or a `JTextArea`.

`commandHandler` is new. This is where your game logic should be. It has a method `handle(string)` which is your old `handleCommand(string)`. It has a `continue()` method that returns a boolean. The boolean should be set to true whenever you want the story to continue, eg when the user enters a command. And finally `events()` (which is a bad name) that returns what has happened since the last command was sent in and gives the users options on what to do next. I've not done an implementation of that, as I just want to give the concept to you. The UI doesn't do any logic processing. The `run()` method doesn't expect anything, it just keeps checking if `continue()` is true. `commandHandler` is where all the bizz is.

Now, you do have a infinite loop running. So if you get any performance issues you could look into `Thread`. This model should support a move to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The separation of presentation and business logic is an intriguing subject to me - I made a game once following an example where the "Model" class, containing the game's rules and logic, was separate from the main game class, which contained display methods, controls and the beginning and ending of a game. Is that the difference you mean? I will attempt to replicate examples of my implementations tomorrow and make more specific suggestions possible!

Comment: @speers Yes. That sounds like what I mean. The [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern is pretty standard, and for good reasons. It makes it much easier to replace the user-interface without altering the logic that does the data-crunching.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. My current program is pretty simple and I think I can easily separate the model from the display, but will probably do so after I have figured out how to make it run in the GUI. I just updated my post with code samples so if you could take another look that would be totally awesome!

Comment: @speers Check my edit. I've given some suggestions that I hope won't be too confusing to understand or implement.

Comment: I think I'm almost there! Any advice on how to write the continue() method?

Comment: Never mind, think I'm making progress - Thanks so much for your help.